# d3 wheel of fortune with infinite rotation or rotation till an event

Tags: animation, svg, d3.js, web-animations

I have spin wheel made using d3.js.

I want the wheel to rotate infinitely or for a given timer value.

On calling the `spin()` function under a `setTimeout`, the wheel does rotates infinitely but it stops with decreasing speed and re-starts slowly. However I want to persist the speed of previous rotation round.

```
function spin(d){
  $('#spin').on("click", null);          
  if(oldpick.length == data.length){
    console.log("done");
    $('#spin').on("click", null);
    return;
  }

  var  ps       = 360/data.length,
  pieslice = Math.round(1440/data.length),
  rng      = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);

  rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);
  const offsetToTop = Math.ceil(360/ps/4) - 1;
  picked = Math.round(data.length - (rotation % 360)/ps) - offsetToTop;
  if(picked >= data.length){
    picked = picked % data.length;
  }else if(picked < 0){
    picked = 0;
  }

  if(oldpick.indexOf(picked) !== -1){
    d3.select(this).call(spin);
    return;
  } else {
    oldpick.push(picked);
  }
  rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/1);

  vis.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
  .each("end", function(){
    console.log(picked);
    oldrotation = rotation;
    alert(data[picked].xp);          
  });
```

}

```
function rotTween(to) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
  return function(t) {
    return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
  };
}
```

Please refer [the codepen](https://codepen.io/mashit/pen/oNmPGoj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [ease](https://d3js.org/d3-ease) for for a d3 transition is "slow-in slow-out" which produces the effect you describe as "stops with decreasing speed and re-starts slowly".  It sounds like you want a "linear" transition which uses the same speed throughout.  To do that use:

```
vis.transition()
  .ease("linear")
  .duration(1000)
  .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
  .each("end", function(){
    console.log(picked);
    oldrotation = rotation;
    alert(data[picked].xp);          
  });
```

Note, you are using a very old version of `d3`.  The call to `.ease` would be different with a more modern version.  My answer is for the version you are using (v3).

**Edits for comments...**

```js
var padding = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 },
  w = 400 - padding.left - padding.right,
  h = 400 - padding.top - padding.bottom,
  r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
  currentRotation = 0,
  color = d3.scale
    .ordinal()
    .range([
      "#70d5fc",
      "#afa9e6",
      "#ffc18f",
      "#ffc5ea",
      "#ffe960",
      "#DC8686",
      "#F4BF96"
    ]);

var data = [
  { label: "0x", value: 1, xp: "you Win 0x" },
  { label: "2x", value: 2, xp: "you Win 2x" },
  { label: "4x", value: 3, xp: "you Win 4x" },
  { label: "5x", value: 2, xp: "you Win 5x" },
  { label: "6x", value: 2, xp: "you Win 6x" },
  { label: "8x", value: 3, xp: "you Win 8x" },
  { label: "10x", value: 4, xp: "you Win 10x" },
  { label: "12x", value: 5, xp: "you Win 12x" },
  { label: "13x", value: 5, xp: "you Win 13x" },
  { label: "8x", value: 3, xp: "you Win 8x" },
  { label: "10x", value: 4, xp: "you Win 10x" },
  { label: "12x", value: 5, xp: "you Win 12x" },
  { label: "12.5x", value: 5, xp: "you Win 12.5x" },
  { label: "8x", value: 3, xp: "you Win 8x" },
  { label: "10x", value: 4, xp: "you Win 10x" },
  { label: "12x", value: 5, xp: "you Win 12x" },
  { label: "12x", value: 5, xp: "you Win 12x" }
];
var svg = d3
  .select("#spinwheel")
  .append("svg")
  .data([data])
  .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + w + "")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);
var container = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "chartholder")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    "translate(" + (w / 2 + padding.left) + "," + (h / 2 + padding.top) + ")"
  );

var vis = container.append("g");

var pie = d3.layout
  .pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function (d) {
    return 1;
  });
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);
var arcs = vis
  .selectAll("g.slice")
  .data(pie)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "slice");

arcs
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", function (d) {
    return arc(d);
  });
arcs
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", function (d) {
    d.innerRadius = 0;
    d.outerRadius = r;
    d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
    return (
      "rotate(" +
      ((d.angle * 180) / Math.PI - 90) +
      ")translate(" +
      (d.outerRadius - 60) +
      ")"
    );
  })
  .attr("font-size", "20")
  .attr("fill", "#ffffff")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function (d, i) {
    return data[i].label;
  });

$("#spin").on("click", spin);
$("#stop").on("click", stop);

function spin(d) {
  $("#spin").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#stop").attr("disabled", null);
  runTransition(currentRotation, currentRotation+360);
}

function stop(d){
  $("#spin").attr("disabled", null);
  $("#stop").attr("disabled", true);
  vis.interrupt();

  const pieSliceInDegrees = 360 / data.length;
        picked = data.length - Math.ceil(currentRotation/pieSliceInDegrees); 

   alert(data[picked].xp);
}

container
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("r", 30)
  .style({ fill: "#ffffff" });

// create recursive closure to run transition endlessly
function runTransition(startR, stopR) {
  
  function rotTween(to) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(startR, stopR);
    return function (t) {
      currentRotation = i(t) % 360;
      return "rotate(" + currentRotation + ")";
    };
  }
  
  vis
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .duration(5000)
    .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
    .each("end", function () {
      runTransition(stopR, stopR+360);
    });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap');

button:focus,
input:focus{
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
a,
a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.wheel-spin-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#spinwheel {
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
    margin: auto;
}

#spinwheel{
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
    margin: auto;
}
#spinwheel svg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 15px solid #CE3816;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #CE3816;
}
.chartholder{

}

.spin-click-button {
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 14px 35px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 479.98px){
    #spinwheel {
        width: 270px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center mb-5 mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4><a href="https://codepen.io/piyushpd/pen/abZOjog" target="_blank">Wheel Spin With get value</a></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center mb-4">
        <button id="spin" class="spin-click-button">Spin the Wheel</button>
        <button id="stop" class="spin-click-button" disabled="true">Stop the Wheel</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <div class="wheel-spin-box">
          <div id="spinwheel">

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you @Mark, but.`ease("linear")` did not help. Please see the updated codepen https://codepen.io/mashit/pen/oNmPGoj?editors=1010.

Comment: Did not help in what way?  I no longer understand your question then.

Comment: please check this code pen ,https://codepen.io/mashit/pen/rNPqLgM  this is exactly what I want to achieve using d3.   
+1 for your help

Comment: In simpler words I need to create a continuously spinning wheel using d3

Comment: See updated answer.  I added a second "stop" button and the start will spin until stop is pressed.  I also simplified some of the math in your example pen.